# Reduce testing time by only running impacted integartion tests

Tags: java, integration-testing, code-coverage, test-coverage

We have a large integration testing Java codebase to cover API and want to reduce testing time by building impact map between tests and web-service source code.

Such functionality, as I know, is provided in TFS, but is there anything for Java?

My search over related topics did not provide any useful information - there are only ideas and experiments, and generally related to unit testing. Such functionality could be built with e.g. Jacoco, but I would like to find ready-to-use tool (including proprietary software) which will help to build and maintain such mapping.

Could you recommend any solutions?

Comment: You can annotate your tests with custom annotations (or categories in JUnit 4) and configure your build tool to run them conditionally.

Comment: What tool or framework are you using for integration testing? Most of them allow categorisation like the unit testing tools.

Comment: We use TestNG for executing tests. Categories and groups - yeah, but still you need to map them dynamically to source code.